# How can I add a HTML control dynamically to the result view in Fable F#?

Tags: f#, fable-f#, elmish

I am trying to understand the very first project that is generated when you create a elmish/fable project like so: `dotnet new fable-react-elmish`:

```
let view (model: Model) dispatch =
   let resultView =
       match model.downloaded with
       | Ok r ->
           h3 [ Style [CSSProp.Color "blue"] ] [ str r ] 
       | Error er ->
           h3 [ Style [CSSProp.Color "red"] ] [ str er ]

   div [] [
       h1 [] [ str "React Elmish demo" ]
       
       button [ OnClick (fun _ -> dispatch OnDownloadClicked) ] [ str "Download" ]
       button [ OnClick (fun _ -> dispatch ResetClicked) ] [ str "Reset" ]
       div [] [ h2 [] [ str "Download result:" ]; resultView ]
   ]
```

I understand that every time one of the functions `OnDownloadClicked` or `ResetClick` is called, a `<h3>` HTML control is displayed as the last control of the HTML page, overwriting the old one. (Probably the whole page is reloaded, but I'm not sure)

But how would I modify the above example in order to have a new `<h3>` element added to the view every time the `OnDownloadClicked` function gets called? In other words: I'd like to have all formerly displayed `<h3>` elements being kept on the view. Any hints (also those pointing to examples) are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code, the type `Model` must be a record that looks something like:

```
type Model = {
   ...
   downloaded: Result<string, string>
   ...
}
```

This `downloaded` field must be updated in the `update` function as a result of `OnDownloadClicked` message.

those are assumptions I'm making based on what you showed here (the `view` function), but I don't know for sure, because you're not showing those parts of the code.

---

Anyway, assuming the assumptions are correct, you can just keep a history of `Result<string, string>` values instead of just the last one. To do this, modify the `Model` type to hold a list of them:

```
type Model = {
   ...
   downloadHistory: list<Result<string, string>>
   ...
}
```

Then have your `update` function append most recent value to the list instead of replacing the field with it.

Then in your `view` function you can produce a list of `h3` tags by mapping the `resultView` function over the `downloadHistory`  list:

```
  let resultView r =
    match r with 
      ...

  ...
  div [] (h2 [] [ str "Download result:" ] :: List.map resultView model.downloadHistory)
```

Comment: All of your assumptions are correct, so I leave the question unedited. It should be comprehensible as it is.